# Selenium RC: how to click an item present in column of a table

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Say i have a table contains nos of rows which is not known. exp
column1 column2 column3
xxx       yyy    "Search Profile"

Column3 for each row contains a Link "Search Profile" now it's clear here that xpath of this link will be changing according to the row. now i want to search a string in column 2 and if present then needs to click it's column3 link.
Can anybody please let me know how to search and click it?

Answer (score 3):

Given a page like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

You could locate the correct value by using XPATH to first find the name of the user.  Then relative to that name you could target the third column relative to the found name in the table.

```
selenium.click("//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='Jane']/parent::tr/td[3]")
```

In this example it finds the first instance of and exact match of 'Jane' in the second column.  Then it backs up to the row and targets (and clicks on) the third column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using selenium.click and giving it the target you're looking for. If you know what text you're searching for in the column 2, you can put that in an XPath expression and click on his friend in column 3.

Something along the lines of :

```
selenium.click("//table[@id='yourTableID']/descendant::tr[td[.='"column2text"']]/td[3]/button);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a count of rows in the generated table. `int rolesTableRowCount = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='your_table_id']/tbody/tr").intValue();`
2. If the count meets your expected result, you could store the text in a specific cell.  `String var = selenium.getText("element_locator");`
3. Check if the contents of `var` matches your test string.
4. If it does click the "Search Profile" link in Column 3.